# What is the best way to daemonize Python scripts?

Tags: python-3.x, daemon

I'm looking for a simple yet effective way to daemonize my Python script. I've tried python-daemon which seemed highly recommended, yet it wasn't working for me. Between Python3 hollering at me for me because the developer turned off IO buffering and issues with /dev/tty, it simply was a mess for me. I've looked into supervisord, yet I don't see a lot of support for Python3. Previously I've tried writing a bash script that utilises nohup and pgrep for ineffective daemonization. I've already read other questions, yet I can't find a solution.

Comment: Why is a py2-based supervisord a problem?

Comment: @sascha From the Github: "Supervisor does not work on Python 3. This is the master branch, which has work-in-progress support for Python 3. Supervisor is very likely to crash, cause subprocesses to hang, or otherwise behave unexpectedly when run on Python 3"

Comment: You seem to misunderstand. supervisord should be run with python 2 (if your text is still true). That does not mean it won't daemonize your python 3 scripts.

Comment: Personally I would prefer to utilize init functions (start-stop-daemon on sysv or unit file for systemd) to daemonise the application; is it an option for You?

Comment: @barti_ddu Yes, I would prefer something that runs in /etc/init.d and can be controlled with start | stop | reload. supervisord works, but you need it installed and configured just to use it. I'd like the daemon to be standalone.

Comment: @Chase [start-stop-daemon](https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/dpkg/start-stop-daemon.8.en.html) binary is found in all deb-based distros (it is a part of `dpkg` actually) and it is even may be possible to use it on other distributions too (it has minimal dependencies, but I've never tried that though).